# How do I switch off loading of pictures in Chrome for Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android, images

In the Android browser one could switch off loading of images to save bandwith, battery and time when the images were not needed.

There seems to be no obvious way to do this under Android 4.4.2 KitKat with Chrome now that it has replaced the old browser.

Does anybody know a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with several 3rd-party browsers, but I don't think you can do it in Chrome. Possibly a root app to do it.